# Insert script in DIP Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, content-type, script, dip

When uploading a document I have a choice field called "Document Type". The choice values are values such as `PDF`, `Word`, `E-mail` and such. When I upload a document with file extention `.docx` the Document Type is to choose the value "Word" automatically. I have got this working by using some jQuery I quickly put together like this:

```
if ($('.ms-fileField-fileExt').text().length > 0) {
  var $ext = $('.ms-fileField-fileExt').text()
  if ($ext.indexOf('doc') >= 0) { $('select[title="Dokument Type"] option[Value="Word"]').attr('selected', 'selected') }
}
```

and similar for other values.

I am creating sub-webs with document libraries based on a custom content type and I need to attach this script to the content type in some way. Adding the script through a CEWP by modifying the standard edit form works for the subweb I am on now, but it won't get applied the next time I make a subweb with document library (this happens automatically when I trigger a specific event). I was thinking that maybe Infopath might be able to do this, but I am unable to find out how.

Is there any way to attach a script to the DIP form in SharePoint 2013 for a custom content type?